# Find IP address of existing Google Search Appliance Device

Tags: google-search-appliance

Interesting one here. I've got a google search appliance that no one has used for ages (yes, everyone knows it's end of life but they want it up) and I've no way of resetting it to factory defaults or even finding out what IP address has been configured on it.

Help! :-)

Comment: Have you tried connecting a machine directly to the appliance and visiting its own internal URL? https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329198#df236e9d-a352-4c2b-ba1a-0c729a6494ed

Comment: I don't know it's IP address so cannot do this. It was changed from teh default 192.168 address in that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have direct access you can follow the instructions Google provides for configuring the GSA with a cross-over cable.  That interface contains a place to view the current IP as well as change it.

However, the license is likely expired on it so it will not function for crawling/serving purposes.  Likely all you can do is have Support wipe it and repurpose the hardware.